# Even when I check for a value in my nullable parameter, the browser still gives me a 500 error

Tags: c#, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

﻿Hi, I am getting this browser console error if the `mainGameId` parameter is null:

```
POST https://example.com/api/devConnection/66544/jwt/null 500
```

But in my controller, I am checking it for null in here:

```
[HttpPost("{id}/Jwt/{mainGameId}")]
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public JsonResult Jwt(Int32 id, Int32? mainGameId)
{
    var game = GameCollection.Get(id);
    var gameTitle = game.Title;
    string token;
    if(mainGameId.HasValue)
    {
         token = CommUtils.GenerateValidToken(mainGameId.ToString(), gameTitle);
    } 
    else
    {
         token = CommUtils.GenerateValidToken(id.ToString(), gameTitle);
    }

    return Json(new { token });
}
```

But even with that check, I still get the error above.

Is there any other type of check I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably don't want `mainGameId.ToString()` as that will stringify the `Int32?`. You probably want `mainGameId.Value.ToString()` as that will stringify the underlying `Int32` value.

Comment: 500 Internal Server error. Have you tried place a breakpoint and debug your API whether which line fails?

Comment: The route is correct,you can try to check the code in your action.

Comment: @YiyiYou thanks! That helped. I will delete this question.